# How to tell a crontab to expire on particular date?

Tags: linux, cron

It is straightforward to execute a task for every 6 hours using the following cron pattern :

`* */6 * * *`

Is it possible to stop the above cron job on particular date, say, `2018-02-10`?

Comment: Sure, make another cronjob for that date that deletes the first one.

Comment: I don't think so. I suggest posting on the [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and asking more generally how you can set up a scheduled recurrent task that will run for a specified time/number of iterations.

Comment: @MarkSetchell but then you'll have that cronjob stay in the crontab and run every year (edit : nevermind, the cronjob could delete both the initial cronjob and itself. I still feel like there must be a more elegant solution)

Comment: Similar to @MarkSetchell solution, simply have the invoked task itself delete the crontab entry.  If that is not directly possible (eg you’re running some native command), then front-end it with a script; written properly, that script would be reusable so you’d keep it around as a permanent utility.  However, I don’t think Cron was ever intended as a fully-featured task scheduler, so check out some of those (eg a quick internet search turned up Chronos which may meet your needs)

Comment: You can use `at` command as well.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time operation, use `at` command scheduler to remove the `cron` entry at a later time.

> DESCRIPTION
>          at and batch read commands from standard input or a specified file which are to be executed at a later time.

```
$ at -f "/usr/local/etc/remove-cron-entry.sh" 6:30 PM "2018-02-10"
```

Above will use `-f` option to read a file and then the rest are time stamps divided in two categories, time and date.

Your removal script can look something like this:

```
$ cat /usr/local/etc/remove-cron-entry.sh
mv /etc/cron.d/my-awesome-cron /tmp/somewhere/my-awesome-cron &> /tmp/cron-move.log
```

`at` is persistent in a reboot and/or login/logout from the user-session. The jobs can be found in `/var/spool/at`.